# Stop timer on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-events

I'm not a JS coder my any means. I know enough to make things do what I want, but couldn't code from scratch. My issue is:

We have a shopping cart that when you add a product the cart shows itself for 4 secs unless the customer hovers over the cart. I can't seem to get it to stop the timeout when the cursor is hovered over it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () { $('#ctl00_ctl00_ctlHeader_divOrderProducts').hide(); }, 4000);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Store the return of `setTimeout()` in a variable, and use that to `clearTimeout()`:

```
// t is a global scope variable.
// Probably a good idea to use something better than 't'
var t;
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Store the return of setTimeout()
  t = setTimeout(function () { $('#ctl00_ctl00_ctlHeader_divOrderProducts').hide(); }, 4000);
});

$('cart-selector').hover(function() {
   if (t) {
    // Call clearTimeout() on hover()
    clearTimeout(t);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your timer to a variable:

```
var timer1 = setTimeout(function () { ... })
```

then use:

```
clearTimeout(timer1)
```

Comment: Diodeus, thank you very much for attending my question! Where would I put this code? Again, I'm not a JS guy at all. It took me 3 days just to get the rollover to work =)

Answer (score 2):

You need to save the return value of `setTimeout()` so you can later use it with `clearTimeout()`.  One way to that is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hideTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('#ctl00_ctl00_ctlHeader_divOrderProducts').hide(); 
    }, 4000);
    $('#ctl00_ctl00_ctlHeader_divOrderProducts').hover(function() {
        if (hideTimer) {
            clearTimeout(hideTimer);
            hideTimer = null;
        }
    });
});
```

If you want to re-enable the timer when the mouse leaves the cart again (assuming `#ctl00_ctl00_ctlHeader_divOrderProducts` is the cart), you can do so like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hideTimer;

    function delayHideCart() {
        if (!hideTimer) {
            hideTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                $('#ctl00_ctl00_ctlHeader_divOrderProducts').hide(); 
            }, 4000);        
        }
    }

    delayHideCart();
    $('#ctl00_ctl00_ctlHeader_divOrderProducts').hover(function() {
        if (hideTimer) {
            clearTimeout(hideTimer);
            hideTimer = null;
        }
    }, function() {
        delayHideCart();
    });
});
```

Comment: @THEDert - since you're fairly new here, do you realize that you are supposed to reward those who have helped you by clicking the up arrow by all answers that you found helpful?  You can click the up arrow on more than one answer.  And it is your responsibility as one who asked a question to select the "best answer" and indicate that by clicking the check mark underneath the arrows (top left or each answer).  That checkmark will turn green indicating this is your selected answer.  You will get reputation points for following proper procedure and the answerers will get rewarded for helping.

Comment: Says I require 15 rep to do so. I have been trying =)

Comment: @THEDert - you should be able to click the checkmark on one answer no matter what your rep.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timeout = setTimeout(function () { $('#ctl00_ctl00_ctlHeader_divOrderProducts').hide(); }, 4000);
    $('#ctl00_ctl00_ctlHeader_divOrderProducts').mouseover(function() { 
         clearTimeout(timeout);
    });
});
```

You save the timeout as a variable and then call clearTimeout when you mouseover the cart and pass in that timeout.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my post

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
 $('#ctl00_ctl00_ctlHeader_divOrderProducts').hide();
if(someCondition)clearTimeout(timer);
}
```